# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from

Tags: python, mysql

I get this error when I call the `executemany` method of the Python `MySQLCursor` class after executing a SELECT statement. Here's the MWE:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL );
```

Here is the Python code. If I comment the two lines indicated, the code works without problems, but it gives the above exception `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from` when it is uncommented. The result is the same even if there is data in the `test` table. I am using Python 3.6.8. Thanks.

```
        import mysql.connector

        db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = "localhost",
            user = "user",
            passwd = "passwd",
            database = "database"
        )
        
        cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True) 
        
        # cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
        # print(cursor.fetchall())

        data = [('A', 'Apple'), ('B', 'Ball'), ]
        sql = "INSERT INTO test (item, title) VALUES (%s,%s)"

        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

Comment: Can you please print the whole stack

Comment: Works for me (albeit connecting to Mariadb)

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for checking. I happen to be using Mariadb as well.